# Collision Response: game character vs. density function

Tags: collision-detection, collision-resolution

### Introduction

I am working on my own "novelty" game-engine project, where the **world is represented by a continuous density function**. It has only one interface, a function that returns the density at a given point:

`float sample(float x,float y,float z);`

I triangulate this density into an **iso-surface for density == 1.0** using marching cubes. The iso-surface is then rendered using OpenGL to display the result on screen.

I have made a function using newton's method to approximate the nearest point in the volume with density equal to 1 (within an error margin) for a certain direction, like this:

`vec3d hitTest(vec3d &origin, vec3d &direction);`

I can use this to perform collision ***detection*** between my main character and the volume, by seeing if the character has transitioned from "outside" to "inside" of the volume during update. I am also able to find the normal at the hit point by doing 3 hit-tests and doing some simple vector math "(a-b).crossProduct(a-c)" or some such.

### Question

How would I be able to calculate the proper collision ***response***?

I am no expert in collision detection/response, so what I am after is a **clear and consise explanation** of what makes a "physically correct" impulse collision under my foretold circumstances.

**Source code** in pseudo/C++ is a big bonus!

Thanks!

Comment: I forget to mention, by "main character" i mean a single 3d point. I will have to elaborate my character further, but right now a single point is good enough!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Common physics engines only need collisions defined by:

- the position of the point of contact
- the surface normal
- the position/velocity of the moving body (managed b the engine itself)

Therefore, you should be able to use a stock physics engine, as long as it supports plugging in custom collision shapes. I recommend doing so, as it gets you a lot of flexibility to add more interesting physics.

Comment: I'll definitely have a look at existing alternatives. But I have added constraints on the projects that need to be considered. For one, it is possible that I cannot rely on floating point because of the "lock-step" nature of my game. If there is a good C++ templated physics engine then that would be awesome (i'd just plug in my own fixed type). Thanks!